# net::ERR_FAILED api call to backend from nextjs with nginx docker

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, next.js

I have 3 docker containers running in mac os.

1. backend - port 5055
2. frontend (next.js) - port 3000
3. nginx - port 80

I am getting **net::ERR_FAILED** for backend api requests when I access from browser (http://localhost:80). I can make a request to backend (http://localhost:5055) in postman and it works well.

Sample api request -  GET http://backend:5055/api/category/show

[image]

What is the reason for this behaviour ?

Thanks.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  backend:
    image: backend-image
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    ports:
      - '5055:5055'
  frontend:
    image: frontend-image
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - backend
  nginx:
    image: nginx-image
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend
```

backend - Dockerfile.prod

```
FROM node:19.0.1-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN yarn install
COPY . ./
ENV PORT 5055
EXPOSE $PORT
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

frontend - Dockerfile.prod

```
FROM node:19-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app
RUN npm install --global pm2
COPY ./package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
USER node
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "npm", "--", "start" ]
```

nginx - Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/nginx/nginx:stable-alpine
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/*
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

nginx - default.conf

```
upstream frontend {
  server frontend:3000;
}

upstream backend {
  server backend:5055;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  ...

  location /api {
    ...
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_redirect off;
    ...
  }

  location /_next/static {
    proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_pass http://frontend;
  }

  location /static {
    proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
    proxy_cache_valid 60m;
    proxy_pass http://frontend;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://frontend;
  }
}
```

frontend - .env.local

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL=http://backend:5055/api
```

frontend - httpServices.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}`,
  timeout: 500000,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
})

...

const responseBody = (response) => response.data

const requests = {
  get: (url, body) => instance.get(url, body).then(responseBody),

  post: (url, body, headers) =>
    instance.post(url, body, headers).then(responseBody),

  put: (url, body) => instance.put(url, body).then(responseBody),
}

export default requests
```

**Edit**

1. nginx logs (docker logs -f nginx 2>/dev/null)

```
172.20.0.1 - - [14/Nov/2022:17:02:39 +0000] "GET /_next/image?url=%2Fslider%2Fslider-1.jpg&w=1080&q=75 HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
172.20.0.1 - - [14/Nov/2022:17:02:41 +0000] "GET /service-worker.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost/service-worker.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
172.20.0.1 - - [14/Nov/2022:17:02:41 +0000] "GET /fallback-B639VDPLP_r91l2hRR104.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost/service-worker.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
172.20.0.1 - - [14/Nov/2022:17:02:41 +0000] "GET /workbox-fbc529db.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost/service-worker.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

2. curl request is working well from nginx container to backend container (curl backend:5055/api/category/show)

**Edit 2**

```
const CategoryCarousel = () => {
   ...
   const { data, error } = useAsync(() => CategoryServices.getShowingCategory())
   ...
}
```

```
import requests from './httpServices'

const CategoryServices = {
  getShowingCategory() {
    return requests.get('/category/show')
  },
}
```

**Edit 3**

When NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL=http://localhost:5055/api

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5055
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1283:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 5055,
  config: {
    ...
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:5055/api',
    method: 'get',
    url: '/products/show',
    data: undefined
  },
  ...
    _options: {
      ...
      protocol: 'http:',
      path: '/api/products/show',
      method: 'GET',
      ...
      pathname: '/api/products/show'
    },
    ...
    },
    _currentUrl: 'http://localhost:5055/api/products/show',
    _timeout: null,
  },
  response: undefined,
  isAxiosError: true,
}
```

Comment: few details should be cleared out before proceeding: 1. have you checked nginx logs? 2. have you tried send request(preferably with curl) inside nginx container?

Comment: please present logs if possible. otherwise it's very difficult to point out what is problem.

Comment: @sungryeol give me few minutes, I'll provide as soon as possible. Also I am using mac os.

Comment: @sungryeol 1. I have edited the question (attached nginx logs). Seems like api call is directly calling from the frontend container to the backend container (since no backend api logs in nginx container),  2. Yes, curl request is working well from nginx container to backend container (curl http://backend:5055/api/category/show)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Docker configuration is all correct

I've read the question again, with the given logs, it seems your configuration is correct all along. However, what you're doing on browser is access violation.

## Docker compose service(hosts) access

Docker services are connected to each other, that means making a request inside another service to another service is possible. What's impossible is a user outside from that service is not accessible to another service. Here's a simpler explanation:

```yaml
# docker-compose.yaml
service-a:
  ports:
    - 3000:3000 # exposed to outside
  # ...
service-b:
  ports:
    - 5000:5000 # exposed to outside
  # ...
```

```bash
# ✅this works! case A
(service-a) $ curl http://service-b:5000
(service-b) $ curl http://service-a:3000
(local machine) $ curl http://localhost:5000
(local machine) $ curl http://localhost:3000
# ❌this does not work! case B
(local machine) $ curl http://service-a:3000
(local machine) $ curl http://service-b:3000
```

When I was reading the question initially, I've missed the part that **the frontend code is accessing unexposed backend service in browser**. This is clearly falls into case B, which will not work.

[image]

## Solution: With server side rendering...

A frontend app is merely a javascript code on your browser. It cannot access to internals. Therefore the request should be corrected:

```
# change from http://backend:5055/api
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL=http://localhost:5055/api
```

But here's better way to solve it. Try access the api inside [server-side code](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props). Since your frontend is Next.js, it is possible to inject backend result to frontend.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const req = await fetch('http://backend:5055/api/...');
  const data = req.json();
  return {
    props: { data }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

## Edit

> (Edit 3) contains frontend logs when NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL is changed to 'localhost' (as you mentioned in the answer). Now the error comes from different api i.e. 'localhost:5055/api/products/show' which is inside a getServerSideProps(). Is this happening because some apis are calling from client side and some are from server side ? If that is the case , How should I fix this ? Thanks

Here's more practical example:

```js
// outside getServerSideProps, getStaticProps - browser
// ❌this will fail 1-a
await fetch('http://backend:5055/...') // 'backend' should be service name
// ✅this will work 1-b
await fetch('http://localhost:5055/...')

// inside getServerSideProps or getStaticProps - internal network
export const getServerSideProps() {
  // ✅this will work 2-a
  await fetch('http://backend:5055/...');
  // ❌this will fail 2-b
  await fetch('http://localhost:5055/...');
}
```

In short, the request has to be either 1-b or 2-a.

> Is this happening because some apis are calling from client side and some are from server side ? If that is the case , How should I fix this ? Thanks

Yes. There are several ways to deal with it.

### 1.Programmatically differentiating the host

```js
const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined';
const HOST_URL = isServer ? 'http://backend:5055' : 'http://localhost:5055';
fetch(HOST_URL);
```

### 2.Manually differentiating the host

```js
// server side
getServerSideProps() {
  // this seems unnecessary and confusing at first sight but it comes very handy later in terms of security.
  fetch('http://backend:5055');
}
// client side
fetch('http://localhost:5055');
```

### 3.Use separate domain for backend(modify hosts file)

This is what I usually resort to when testing services with domain name in local environment.

Modifying [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)), means `exampleurl.com` will be resolved as `localhost` in the OS. In this case, production environment must use separate domains and host file setup is required. The service must be exposed to public. Please refer to this [document on modifying hosts file](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-edit-hosts-file).

```yaml
# docker-compose.yaml
services:
  backend:
    ports:
      - 5050:5050
# ...
```

```
# hosts file
127.0.0.1   exampleurl.com
# ...
```

```js
// in this case,
// development == local development
const IS_DEV = process.NODE_ENV = 'development';
// hosts file does not resolve port. it's necessary for local development.
const BACKEND_HOST = 'exampleurl.com'
const BACKEND_URL = IS_DEV ? `${BACKEND_HOST}:5050` : BACKEND_HOST;
// client-side
fetch(BACKEND_URL);

// server-side
getServerSideProps() {
  fetch(BACKEND_URL);
}
```

There are many clever ways to solve this problem but there is no "always right" answer. Take your time to think which method best fits to your case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried with NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL=http://localhost:5055/api before, it did not work. The reason is in that case, localhost is identified as the frontend container's localhost not the backend container's localhost.

Comment: I added (Edit 2) - flow of the current frontend to backend api call

Comment: Also if I put my machine's 'IP address' instead of 'localhost' or 'backend', this works fine in browser. But I want to use container name instead the IP since IP is not static.

Comment: @JohnStuart docker does not discriminate which service should be exposed as localhost. whichever service with exposed port should be accessible from `localhost`. the statement(localhost is identified as the frontend container's localhost not the backend container's localhost) does not make any sense.

Comment: @JohnStuart the mentioned frontend api call(edit 2) does not clarify if the request is happening inside server side or client side. it decides which backend host to use. if frontend container or nginx container has no problem making request to backend service, then it's still frontend issue. it can be solved by the same method mentioned in this answer. if the request is happening from the server side code, IP address is totally unnecessary.

Comment: (Edit 3) contains frontend logs when NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL is changed to 'localhost' (as you mentioned in the answer). Now the error comes from different api i.e. 'http://localhost:5055/api/products/show' which is inside a getServerSideProps(). Is this happening because some apis are calling from client side and some are from server side ? If that is the case , How should I fix this ? Thanks.

Comment: @JohnStuart I've added more explanation. Hope it helps 

Comment: Thanks. This approach will resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

in nginx.conf you need to specify the backend port too and also the base path (/api):

```
location /api {
  ...
  proxy_pass http://backend:5055/api;
}
```

Comment: It is already mentioned. i.e. upstream frontend {
  server frontend:3000;
}

upstream backend {
  server backend:5055;
} at nginx - default.conf.

Comment: ah you are right, but maybe you still need to add the api base path: `proxy_pass http://backend/api;`

Comment: That is defined under NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL=http://backend:5055/api (frontend - .env.local). Thing is next js frontend server call to backend api is refused in browser level. But inside the frontend container when you do the curl to backend api it works well.